# look all human up close

Tags: meaning-in-context

> IN RELAXED pre-9/11 days, your columnist was once permitted to sit in the cockpit for a flight from Delhi to London. The experience left him with mixed feelings about flight safety. On the one hand, the two Canadian pilots who generously included him in their competition to get through the first-class dessert menu were experienced and relaxed. On the other, the plane was on autopilot almost the whole way. And the only time one of them was called upon to intervene—when a coil of wiring suddenly let off sparks—he didn’t seem to know what he was doing. Even the most technically proficient operations can **look all too human up close**.

---

What does it mean here? look like a human?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an expression "He's only human", and it means "he is flawed, imperfect. He is not a god or an angel".

So saying the pilot's operation was "all too human" means that it was imperfect. The pilot. The phrase "all too X" is used to emphasise something is the case, to an unwelcome degree.  The pilot is a flawed human, and more flawed than we want when we watch him closely.